# Microsoft.Xml.XQuery math expression error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xquery

I'm newer in Microsoft.Xml.XQuery, when I'm trying to run a xquery with math expression like sum i have  the error : Cannot apply Add to non integer data.

XML:

```
<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>
```

XQuery:

```
for $item in document("xqt")/bookstore/book[price < '30']
return $item/year/text()  +  $item/year/text()
```

C#:

```
  XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
        doc1.LoadXml(rteXml.Text);
        XQueryNavigatorCollection navCol = new XQueryNavigatorCollection();
        navCol.AddNavigator(doc1.CreateNavigator(), "xqt");

        XQueryExpression expr = new XQueryExpression(rteXQuery.Text.Trim().Replace("\\n", " "));

        XQueryNavigator nav = expr.Execute(navCol);

        rteOutput.Text = nav.ToXml();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Never heard of this API. Is it part of SQL Server?

Comment: See these  http://xqueryservices.com    or www.pietsieg.com/articles\xquery\beginner\Using XQuery in ASP.NET - OLD MS XQuery Demo\Using XQuery in ASP.NET.htm

Comment: Neither of those links works for me. The second isn't even a link.

Comment: http://www.pietsieg.com/articles%5Cxquery%5Cbeginner%5CUsing%20XQuery%20in%20ASP.NET%20upd%20-%20OLD%20MS%20XQuery%20Demo%5CXQuery.htm is a valid link to the ancient article on an experimental version of XQuery that was never made into a product.

Comment: So, did you know you were working with something a decade old and unsupported? If you want a supported version of XQuery, you can get it from [Saxonica](http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for $item in document("xqt")/bookstore/book[price < '30']
return sum($item/year/text(), $item/price/text())
```